# How to convert data object getting from Room Relation into a custom Parent -Child Type Object in android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, relation

Suppose I have two tables Parent and child.

[This is the Parent Table Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGJ7h.png)
[This is the Child Table schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2n3Ha.png)

when we apply to join(Relation) on these two table like this
[Relation on these two tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBxOI.png). But this returns a list of objects that contain both parent and child data. But the requirement of the model for nested recycler view is the parent-child object like this.
[Parent Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9kW3.png)
[Child Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwHWQ.png)

So, the main problem is to convert the list getting after applying relation to the parent-child type list.

I am a fresher and not so much knowledge about Room DB, if I follow some wrong way please let me correct it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Replace parent and child in relation:

```
data class BagWithSkuViewModel (
    @Embedded
    val bag: BagEntity,
    @Relation(parentColumn = "bag_uid", entityColumn = "bag_id", entity = SkuEntity.class)
    val skus: List<SkuEntity>
)
```

Now you can convert it to your Parent Model, changed to data class:

```
data class HeadBagModel(var bagUid: String? = null, 
    var bagWeight: String? = null, 
    var bagStatus: String? = null, 
    var skuList: ArrayList<ScuEntity>? = null)

fun BagWithSkuViewModel.toHeadBagModel(): HeadBagModel {
    return HeadBagModel(this.bag.bag_uid, 
        this.bag.bag_weight, 
        this.bag.bagStatus, 
        this.skus) // your SkuEntity and ChildSkuModel are almost same, but if you need ChildSkuModel here, you can add another converter
}
```